# C-C bond lengths in hydrocarbons

Tags: bond

We had a question in a rest comparing the bond lengths of hydrocarbons fluorides, and the answer key says CF3- CF3's supposed to have a longer C-C bond than H3C- CH2--F.

Why is this so? Wouldn't the C-F bond have less s-character, leading to increase in s-character in the other bonds? That way, CF3-CF3 should have the shortest bond length.
Thanks!

Comment: I would argue mainly that fluorine is bigger than hydrogen (more electrons) increasing repulsion. You might also argue that the electron withdrawing tendency of the fluorines leaves a reduced amount of bonding charge between the carbons.

Comment: Alternatively said write two delta+ on both carbon atoms. This immediately aids.